# How to fetch data in the background, when the app is terminated and when app is in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate, background-fetch

I'm new to iOS. I have googled a lot for this question, tried many approaches and finally, I'm here.

In my application, I have to push a notification in the background when a new record is found in the API response. As per Apple documentation, I have implemented `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` as below:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    //User Login status from NSUserdefaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL Is_User_Logged_in = [defaults boolForKey:IS_USER_LOGGED_IN];
    if(Is_User_Logged_in){
        NSLog(@"background fetch started");

        //fetchDataFromAPIs method calls 3 API's here
        // and if a new record found, inserts into the local sqlitedb
        if([self fetchDataFromAPIs])
        {
            //getUpdatedInfo method checks the new record in the local sqlitedb
            // and fires a notification
            if([self getUpdatedInfo])
            {
                NSLog(@"Content Uploaded and pushed notification");
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:REFRESH_HOME object:self];
                NSLog(@"Time: %@", [Constants getCurrentTimeStamp]);
            }
            else{
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
                NSLog(@"Time: %@", [Constants getCurrentTimeStamp]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above method fires the notification when the app is in the background but when the app is terminated nothing is happening. Fetch time interval is unpredictable.

I have set minimum time interval to perform background fetch in the application delegate method as below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [self registerForRemoteNotifications];
    return YES;
}
```

How to make `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` to run in the background for certain regular time intervals without fail?

How to run `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` when the app is terminated by the user?

Also, I'm running an NSTimer with a regular time interval in the foreground of the app to show the updates as badge number and a notification as shown below:

```
   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(UpdatePages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

As I already implemented `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` in the application delegate, should I skip this `NSTimer` in the foreground?

Please help to sort this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't schedule for a specific interval. iOS will schedule your fetch based on how often your function returns new data and how much time it takes to run. If the user terminates your app by swiping up, iOS assumes the user didn't want that app to run, so it won't run until the user relaunches it. Also, you don't call the completion handler if the user isn't logged in. This can result in your app being penalised with longer fetch intervals

Comment: HI @Paulw11, Thank you so much for your reply. if my API calls and DB operations take a long time then IOS will never schedule a fetch? 

I'm using NSuserdefaults as a session. If user logged out, then what the point to show a new notification?